# VBA - username in both Windows and OSX

Tags: windows, macos, vba, excel, cross-platform

I'm writing VBA code to gather input from several xlsx files and combine them into a single master sheet. Since the users of this sheet are mixed Windows and OSX users, my code needs to be universal across both platforms.

One of the things I'd like to achieve is to determine the user's username. This can be done using `environ("username")` on Windows and `MacScript` on OSX. However, below code cannot be compiled on Mac, since it doesn't know `environ()`.

> ```
> OS_IS_MAC = Application.OperatingSystem Like "*Mac*"
> If OS_IS_MAC Then
>    sMyScript = "set userName to short user name of (system info)" & vbNewLine & "return userName"
>    USERNAME = MacScript(sMyScript)
> ```
>
> Else
>
> ```
>    USERNAME = Environ("UserName")
> ```
>
> End If

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use conditional compilation:

```
#If Mac Then
   sMyScript = "set userName to short user name of (system info)" & vbNewLine & "return userName"
   USERNAME = MacScript(sMyScript)
#Else
   USERNAME = Environ("UserName")
#End If
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! That's perfect (and helps w/ some other Mac/Windows issues I had).

Answer (score 0):

One of these might be simpler:

```
USERNAME = Environ("USER")
```

or

```
USERNAME = Environ("LOGNAME")
```

And they work as shown on the Mac.